# Smooth lines of a graph in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

[I have a chart like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOPAa.png)

But I wanted the graph to have smoother lines

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uINl1.jpg)

my code is written like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(vento.direcao, vento.vermelho, '-', color='red')
ax.fill_between(vento.direcao, vento.IC_2, vento.IC_1, alpha=0.2, color='#4d4d4d', linestyle='-.' )
ax.set_title('Periodo de Retorno - Vermelho', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Velocidade do Vento (m/s)')
ax.set_xlabel('Componente Direcional')
```

[image: MY DATE]

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

`scipy` has a module for this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline

smooth_x = np.linspace(min(vento.direcao), max(vento.direcao), 10)  

smooth_y = spline(vento.direcao, vento.vermelho, smooth_x)

plt.plot(smooth_x,smooth_y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: spline has been removed from  the version I use.

I did it

from scipy.interpolate import splrep

smooth_x = np.linspace(min(vento.IC_2), max(vento.IC_1), 8)  

smooth_y = splrep(vento.direcao, vento.vermelho, smooth_x)

plt.plot(smooth_x,smooth_y)
plt.show()

But return this error

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (8,) and (3,)

Comment: Do you know another alternative?

Comment: @EmilleMazzaro [csaps](https://pypi.org/project/csaps/) or if you are unable to install modules into your workspace - try simply adding a mathematical equation for interpolation - If I get some time, I can try to help.